# gwt-maven-plugin fails with NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I've downloaded [GWTP samples](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP-Samples) from github.

I've tried to build it using Maven(mvn clean install), but I've got:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) on project gwtp-sample-basic-spring: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile (default) on project gwtp-sample-basic-spring: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:592)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:323)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:247)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:427)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:121)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.7.0:compile failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:576)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.ClasspathBuilder.buildClasspathList(ClasspathBuilder.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.AbstractGwtMojo.getClasspath(AbstractGwtMojo.java:223)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.compile(CompileMojo.java:443)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.CompileMojo.doExecute(CompileMojo.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.shell.AbstractGwtShellMojo.execute(AbstractGwtShellMojo.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:105)
    ... 21 more
```

Currently I can't find any helpful information about NPE for gwt-maven-plugin. What I'm doing wrong? In which direction I should look to find out the reason of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at org.codehaus.mojo.gwt.ClasspathBuilder.buildClasspathList(ClasspathBuilder.java:71)
> ```

[That line](https://github.com/gwt-maven-plugin/gwt-maven-plugin/blob/gwt-maven-plugin-2.7.0/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt/ClasspathBuilder.java#L71) would mean that the logger hasn't been initialized. Which Maven version are you using?
The plugin has been built and validated with Maven 3.2 (and was developed with 3.0), and I just tried with Maven 3.3 and integration tests pass too; but it could be a Maven versioning issue if you're not using one of those versions.

Comment: I build it under maven 3.0.9

Comment: Finally, I've downloaded maven 3.2.5 and tried with new clean local repo - everything is OK now. Thank you

Comment: [3.0.9 doesn't exist](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html); did you mean 2.0.9? gwt-maven-plugin requires Maven 3. If you meant 3.0.5 then this is strange because that's still my default install and all integration-tests passed for me.

Comment: My bad.
The actual output of "mvn -version" starts with
"Apache Maven 3.0-alpha-7 (r921173; 2010-03-10 10:31:07+1200)"
But my folder is called apache-maven-3.0.9